# EF not throwing DbUpdateConcurrencyException despite conflicting updates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am using EF 6.x (code-first) on a Web API server with web clients and I need to implement concurrency handling.  The problem is that I cannot even get EF to generate an exception.

Most examples that I have found seems to not be using "detached entities", where the DTO is sent to a web client where it is updated and then saved back to the server at a later time (which is my scenario).

Let's say I have a Company record:

```
public class Company 
{
    int CompanyId { get; set; }
    string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

1) User A pulls up company with `Id` = 0, `RowVersion` is 0x0000000000002B0A

2) I run `UPDATE Company SET CompanyName = 'Acme Changed, Inc.' WHERE CompanyId = 0` to simulate a change by another user.  `RowVersion` changes to 0x0000000000002B0B

3) User A changes CompanyName to "Acme, The Great!" and clicks Save (from browser)

4) The Company DTO arrives at Web API server with `CompanyName` = "Acme, The Great!" and the old `RowVersion` = 0x0000000000002B0A

5) I retrieve the Company record from the DB, update it and save it:

```
public void UpdateCompany(Company updatedCompany)
{
    var dbCompany = Context.Companies.SingleOrDefault(r => r.CompanyId == updatedCompany.CompanyId);
    dbCompany.CompanyName = updatedCompany.CompanyName;
    dbCompany.RowVersion = updatedCompany.RowVersion;  // Set RowVersion to the passed in original RowVersion 0x0000000000002B0A

    try
    {
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        // Expected: exception thrown (but does not happen).
    }
}
```

Instead of a concurrency exception, it just saves the record and updates `RowVersion` to 0x0000000000002B0C.

What am I missing?

I need a way to detect changes, deletion, etc. to prevent saving dirty data.  I guess I could roll my own checks, but the actual objects are complex with many nested child objects (one or more levels).

Any pointers on best practices on this would also be appreciated...

Comment: The problem you described doesn't have a concurrency problem. You are getting latest version of data from database and updating it and saving it. Why EF would have problem with that. If the row being updated is already deleted or is locked by some other query or two process are trying to change the same row at the same time these coluld be  problem. But most of the time EF and sql server tries their best to handle it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I had the idea that EF would detect that the RowVersion of the record that I am trying to save does not match the record in the DB and thus know that the record is dirty.  If that is not the case, what is the proper / best practices for handling the above concurrency problem in this type of scenario??

Comment: In your example you are not saving the row which you retrieved earlier. You are retrieving and saving the latest version of row. I am not sure what's your intention here. Are you solving a problem of a real application or just getting to know EF? Also what exactly is the use case here? Do you want EF to throw exception if the entity is modified by some other process? You can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, it is a real application.  Multiple web clients could potentially work on the same record and I need to make sure I catch and handle any conflicting changes, such as the one I outlined in my question.   Yes, I want EF to let me know if I am trying to save dirty data, so that I can take appropriate action.  I could roll my own solution, comparing the RowVersion, etc., but I was hoping EF could help me with this.  My scenario must be fairly common (any web-based multi-user data entry app)...

Comment: Concurrent situation handled by RowVersion in this scenario is when you update the entity (read, modify, save) and between the read and save was a concurrent write to the same entity

Comment: If you want detect concurrency between the Get and Update action then you have to send the current RowVersion to the client and back for the Update

Comment: @SirRufo I am sending the RowVersion to the client and then back to the server for the update.  From your first comment it appears that I will have to roll my own mechanism for detecting conflicting updates, etc. in the scenario outlined in my question.  Is this correct?

Comment: You can, but you don't have to. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got this working.  In step 5 of my question, I changed this line:

```
dbCompany.RowVersion = updatedCompany.RowVersion;
```

To this:

```
Context.Entry(dbCompany).OriginalValues["RowVersion"] = updatedCompany.RowVersion;
```

Now EF throws a DbUpdateConcurrencyException when trying to save dirty data!

Comment: Awesome.  Most tutorials I see use TryUpdateModel, which I refuse to use in my MVC app.  This did the trick for me.

Comment: This also solved the issue for me. It worries me though, I am not sure why I have to do it this way. I wonder if the internal tracker is getting confused.

Comment: @VictorioBerra, the internal tracker is not confused. Actually, it's working correctly. EF keeps track of the original values (see above) which basically allow EF to compare how things were when the row was read and see if it still in the same state when the record is being updated. If some other user made another update to the same record, then you have a concurrency exception. Since the company object went out of process, Lars335 simply redefined that original value when the database was read for the first time. It takes a bit to grasp the idea, but you'll get there.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is the row version is special and treated in a special way by EF? It is completely ignoring the RowVersion unless we alter the original values which is a low level bag of properties that your average EF developer should very rarely need to poke around in. You can see how this is very confusing no? Also the docs go into great detail on row version but only mention modifying the original values once and it hides that within code samples.

Comment: a little bit more elegant, as it doesn't use strings for keys (bad for refactoring etc): `Context.Entry(dbCompany).Property(c => c.RowVersion).OriginalValue = updatedCompany.RowVersion;`

Answer (score 2):

I am working with an abstraction of Entity Framework and I don't have access to the EF context, but I found that writing

`updatedCompany.RowVersion.CopyTo(dbCompany.RowVersion, 0);`

solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from @Lars335 I wrote a little helper method to reset original values for concurrency tokens

```
    public static void ResetConcurrencyValues(this DbContext context, Object entity) {
        var lEntry = context.Entry(entity);
        foreach (var lProperty in lEntry.Metadata.GetProperties().Where(x => x.IsConcurrencyToken)) {
            lEntry.OriginalValues[lProperty] = lEntry.CurrentValues[lProperty];
        }
    }
```

Which then makes the record update become

```
    _context.Update(user);
    _context.ResetConcurrencyValues(user);
    var lCount = await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

However, I too am of the mind that thinks if the *current* value of the token is not the same as the stored value, then a concurrency exception should be thrown. The updated record cannot be re-read until after the conflicting change has been made, so will never have the original value in it.